# How to add a space when you're multiplying variables in python

Tags: python, printing

Here is my code

```
print("Type in another set of words")
    x = input()
    print("Now type in how many times you want it to appear (WHOLE NUMBERS ONLY!)")
    c = int(input())
    print(x * c)
```

I want to add a space between every time the word is multiplied. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Use [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to place a space between a sequence of strings:

```
print(' '.join([x] * c))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string formatting:

```
print('{} '.format(x)*c)
```