# How to get space for cloning the character accurately in print statement of Python?

Tags: python

So I am trying to doing string multiplication

```
print("string"*2)
```

but it result in

```
stringstring
```

how to get whitespaces in between them. But without any complex functions. I have trying sep and end keywords but didn't got resultant output.

Comment: `' '.join(['string'] * 2)`

Comment: `print("string "*2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a space when you're multiplying variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938965/how-to-add-a-space-when-youre-multiplying-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with multiplying a string, is that it results a new string. So you can't know the separation point in that new big string. Instead multiply a list and then either use [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)'s arguments or [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print(*["string"] * 2, sep=' ')
```

Or:

```
print(' '.join(["string"] * 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a list multiplication

```py
print(" ".join(["string"] * 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
print(" ".join(["string"] * 2))
```

Decomposing that, `str.join(list)` joins every item in the list by using the `str` value. `list * 2` duplicates that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do :

```
>>> print("string "*2)
string string
```

if a space at the end doesn't matter to you

Comment: +1. This is simple enough that join isn't needed. In general, if a is the string, b is the separator (space here) and n is the multiplied number, the operation simply can be done as `((a+b)*n)[:-len(b)]`.

Comment: @Mercury My instinct was that this will be less efficient because of the slicing creating a new string. To my surprise this is much (much) better... [see this](https://replit.com/@TomerKalish/LameLameRuntimes#main.py).

Comment: @Tomerikoo awesome! I didn't know that the difference would be this significant.